# How to count the number of days before and after an event where a condition is met?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in `R` where I am trying to count the consecutive number of days before and after an event where a condition is met.

Example Data:

```
Event <- c("No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No")
Date <- c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06")
Value <- c(0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0)

df <- as.data.frame((cbind(Date, Event, Value)))
```

I've tried doing multiple different approaches, including using leads and lags, but essentially, I am trying something like this:

```
df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(Cond <- if_else(Value > 1, "Yes", No),
         Cons_Days = if_else(Event == "Yes", cumsum(Cond == "Yes"), 0))
```

But this creates cumulative sums from the entire dataset - not just from the yes' around the time of the Event.

I essentially want to count the number of consecutive days if an event happens (Event == "Yes"), and count the number of days around that event that the condition is met where Value > 1.

The final dataframe I am looking to create looks like this:

```
Event <- c("No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No")
Date <- c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06")
Value <- c(0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0)
Cond <- c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No")
Cons_Days <- c(0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0)

df_final <- as.data.frame(cbind(Event, Date, Value, Cond, Cons_Days))
```

Comment: Hi @Kate and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please clarify the meaning of `value`? The `2021-01-01` line has "0" for `value`. Does that mean there've been zero days since the previous event? Perhaps you could help me grasp your intent regarding "consecutive days." Hoping to you help you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of using `ifelse()` for a binary test it is more concise and
   convenient for downstream tasks to use a condition that evaluates
   to a logical (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) variable.
2. We can use `dplyr::consecutive_id()` to identify all consecutive entries
   that belong to one event.
3. By grouping the data by the `Event_ID` `cumsum()` is now applied only to
   the group of values that belong to one event.
4. We use `max()` on `cumsum()` and `ifelse()` to set non-event entries to
   `0` to achieve your desired output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(Cond = Value > 1,
         Event_ID = consecutive_id(Cond)) |>
  group_by(Event_ID) |>
  mutate(Cons_Days = max(cumsum(Cond)),
         Cons_Days = ifelse(Event == "Yes", Cons_Days, 0))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Groups:   Event_ID [3]
#>   Date       Event Value Cond  Event_ID Cons_Days
#>   <chr>      <chr> <chr> <lgl>    <int>     <dbl>
#> 1 2021-01-01 No    0     FALSE        1         0
#> 2 2021-01-02 No    2     TRUE         2         0
#> 3 2021-01-03 Yes   3     TRUE         2         3
#> 4 2021-01-04 No    2     TRUE         2         0
#> 5 2021-01-05 No    1     FALSE        3         0
#> 6 2021-01-06 No    0     FALSE        3         0
```

This works for the example data you provided, but there might be situations in your actual data where it might fail. If so, please provide appropriate example data in your question.